# When to Use * in SQL Query Containing JOINs & Aggregations?

Tags: sql, join, aggregate-functions

#### Question

- `Web_events` table contain `id`,..., `channel`,`account_id`
- `accounts` table contain `id`, ..., `sales_rep_id`
- `sales_reps` table contains `id`, `name`

Given the above tables, write an SQL query to determine the number of times a particular `channel` was used in the `web_events` table for each name in `sales_reps`. Your final table should have three columns - the name of the `sales_reps`, the `channel`, and the number of occurrences. Order your table with the highest number of occurrences first.

#### Answer

```
SELECT s.name, w.channel, COUNT(*) num_events
FROM accounts a
JOIN web_events w
ON a.id = w.account_id
JOIN sales_reps s
ON s.id = a.sales_rep_id
GROUP BY s.name, w.channel
ORDER BY num_events DESC;
```

---

The `COUNT(*)` is confusing to me. I don't get how SQL figure out that`COUNT(*)` is `COUNT(w.channel)`. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Aggergate functions like `count()` return results for each group you define.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` means "count rows", i.e. the number of rows grouped together. It is the same as `COUNT(w.channel)`, but only if `w.channel` cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: Based on the `Group By` clause. Just to add a point, In your case `count(*)` may not be same as `count(w.channel)`. You have `s.name` also in the group by which means `count(*)` will give the count based on the combination of `s.name` & `w.channel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't get how SQL figure out that COUNT(*) is COUNT(w.channel)

`COUNT()` is an aggregation function that counts the number of rows that match a condition.  In fact, `COUNT(<expression>)` in general (or `COUNT(column)` in particular) counts the the number of rows where the expression (or column) is not `NULL`.

In general, the following do *exactly* the same thing:

- `COUNT(*)`
- `COUNT(1)`
- `COUNT(<primary key used on inner join>)`

In general, I prefer `COUNT(*)` because that is the SQL standard for this.  I can accept `COUNT(1)` as a recognition that `COUNT(*)` is just feature bloat.  However, I see no reason to use the third version, because it just requires excess typing.

More than that, I find that new users often get confused between these two constructs:

- `COUNT(w.channel)`
- `COUNT(DISTINCT w.channel)`

People learning SQL often think the first really does the second.  For this reason, I recommend sticking with the simpler ways of counting rows.  Then use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` when you really want to incur the overhead to count unique values (`COUNT(DISTINCT)` is more expensive than `COUNT()`).